# how to use if statement in android studio without using setText

Tags: android

I want to use if statement in android studio but without using setText

```
    dayText.setText(forecast.getDay());
    if (forecast.getDay().equals("Mon")){
        dayText.setText("السبت");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Tue")){
        dayText.setText("الاحد");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Wed")){
        dayText.setText("الاثنين");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Thu")){
        dayText.setText("الثلاثاء");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Fri")){
        dayText.setText("الاربعاء");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Sat")){
        dayText.setText("الخميس");
    }else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Sun")){
        dayText.setText("الجمعة");
    }
```

if there is any example

Comment: this is very unclear question, you dont state what you want toi achieve

Comment: what do you want to achieve?Do you want to setText on TextView without using setText or What????

Comment: Why don't you use the normal **string localization**, instead?

Comment: @Rotwang any example ?

Comment: .. google for it?

Comment: you don't have always to set text when using if. You just need to remove `setText`, and you will be using `if` without `setText`. That's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get what you are looking to do but first initialize the String as `public String getDay;` after you can check the if statement like, if you add more code maybe i can help you more.

```
if(getDay.equals("Mon")) {
 /** do something **/
}
getDay = day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
public String getDay() {
        if (getDay().equals("Mon")){
            Log.e("Success","Mon");
        }
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, what you want is not to have so many setTexts? This will work for that purpose.

```
String finalText = "";
if (forecast.getDay().equals("Mon")){
    finalText = "السبت";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Tue")){
    finalText = "الاحد";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Wed")){
    finalText = "الاثنين";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Thu")){
    finalText = "الثلاثاء";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Fri")){
    finalText = "الاربعاء";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Sat")){
    finalText = "الخميس";
}else if (forecast.getDay().equals("Sun")){
    finalText = "الجمعة";
}
dayText.setText(finalText);
```